# Using raw_input to call an instance

Tags: python, class, instances

I am making an algorithm in Python 2.7 for fantasy football and i'm using it to compare players. I made all the players instances in a class, I want the user to be able to choose which instances to compare with the algorithm:

```
class QB:

    def __init__(self, td, yards, fpts, fptspg, ranking, int):

        self.td = td

        self.yards = yards

        self.fpts = fpts

        self.fptspg = fptspg

        self.ranking = ranking

        self.int = int 


Brady = QB(15,4342,234,21,1,3)
Manning = QB(12,1234,433,12, 2,8)


def alg(userinput):
    alg = X.td*10+X.yards-X.int*10
    print alg
```

How can I make "X" be whatever the user chooses?
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you provide the user with a list of options to select from

Comment: Because there are a 100+ instances which would be too many for a list of options.

Answer (score 2):

You could put your players into a dictionary:

```
players = dict(
    Brady=QB(15,4342,234,21,1,3)
    Manning=QB(12,1234,433,12, 2,8)
    )
```

Now, define `alg` as:

```
def alg(userinput):
    X = players[userinput]
    alg = X.td*10+X.yards-X.int*10
    print alg
```

Then it can be called as:

```
alg("Brady")
```

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps and eval function?

```
class QB:
    def __init__(self, td, yards, fpts, fptspg, ranking, int):
        self.td = td
        self.yards = yards
        self.fpts = fpts
        self.fptspg = fptspg
        self.ranking = ranking
        self.int = int 


Brady = QB(15,4342,234,21,1,3)
Manning = QB(12,1234,433,12, 2,8)
#print(Brady.td)

def alg(userinput):
    X=eval(userinput)
    alg = X.td*10+X.yards-X.int*10
    print(alg)
```

..
    Example

```
alg("Brady")
```

results

```
4462
```

or

```
alg("Manning")
```

results

```
1274
```

Comment: Don't suggest `eval` as an alternative to using a `dict`.

Comment: @repzero As a good reason **why** `eval` is not a great suggestion ... what would happen if the user entered the following as the player name: `__import__('shutil').rmtree('/')`